# Is Labeling toolbar no longer available in QGIS 3.8.2 running on Mint 19.2 Tina?

Tags: qgis-3

[image][image][image]It seems the Labeling toolbar is no longer available with this version on Mint 19.2 Tina, though I have seen it on the Windows version of QGIS 3.8. Moving labels is a vital part of a large research and cartography project needed soon by my publisher.

Comment: can you add the contents of the help->about tab too?

Answer (score 1):

I think the labeling tool bar has not gone anywhere in 3.8 (unless you told it to).

[image]

To re-add it to the display, right click on an empty part of the grey toolbar background and click the box next to label toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Yes I've tried that and the Label Toolbar is not listed...

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the toolbar menu to your question?

Comment: Very difficult - please tell me how. I can pull up the toolbar and panel menu, where Label Toolbar would be selected, but the moment I attempt a printscreen (Gnome Screenshot) by hitting PrtScr or Alt + PrtScr - the menu vanishes.... What to do?

Comment: I use gimp to capture menus

Comment: Thanks mate-screenshot with delay worked to capture the menu...

Comment: Maybe "reset user interface" from Menu settings -  options - system helps?

Comment: Good try Babel - I hadn't spotted that control. Unfortunately it didn't work - tried it twice. Thanks though...

Comment: Just re-installed QGIS - v3.8.3 - Label toolbar still not present. System configuration remains the same..

Comment: Did you delete the QGis folder in your user profile before reinstalling?

Comment: yes, or whatever windows calls it

Comment: I assume you mean ~/.config/QGIS ? I hadn't, but I removed QGIS again, removed thsi directory and re-installed. Label Toolbar still isn't listed I'm afraid... I'm working still in Linux not Windows.

Comment: I have just completely installed QGIS 3.10, still running on Mint 19.2 Tina and there is still no labelling toolbar. What to do? Windows? Gulp...

Answer (score 0):

I'm indebted to Randal Hale  who came up with the solution to this problem. Turns out that my default profile:

~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default

was corrupt. Answer: create a new profile with

Settings>User Profiles>New Profile...

~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/profiles.ini now has the content:

> [core]
>   defaultProfile=test

if the new profile was named "test"